# How to persist non-trainable variables in tf.Estimator checkpoint?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to include a [Dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) layer that is not trainable and initialized as an identity matrix, as part of my tensorflow Estimator.  The intuition is for this Dense layer to pass through its inputs during standard training and a fine tuning step afterward.  The catch is that I don't want these weights updated at all during the initial round, only during fine tuning.

I can do several things to make these weights non-trainable, including using the trainable argument in the Dense constructor or by filtering out anything with dense in its name before passing to MomentumOptimizer.compute_gradients().

But in either case (make dense non-trainable or just don't pass it to optimizer), tf will throw an error saying that it cannot find a key related to the dense layer.

I understand that since on the first run, where dense is non-trainable, that it won't be persisted in the checkpoint file.  Likewise, if it's filtered out from being passed to compute_gradients, then the same issue occurs.

Is there any method to just persist untrained variables, even with just their initialized values, across runs?

> NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key dense/kernel/Momentum not
>   found in checkpoint

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question here because it wasn't immediately obvious to me, as tf documentation doesn't seem to make it clear.  If you want to introduce a new trainable variable, then it will need to fundamentally be a different model in later ones.  Thus in order to handle fine-tuning of existing weights, those existing weights in the new model must be resolved from the warm start settings.

So train a model, conditionally not including the fine-tune layer when your Estimator's model function runs.  Train the existing model and then create another model that is separate.  Technically this just means you need to use a fresh model directory, but warm start settings should point to the model you trained beforehand.

On fine-tuning runs, your model function should conditionally include the fine-tuning layers, but it should restore the weights from the previous run setting the warm start settings to look at previous model directory.